# How can i pass password in a GetCredential in powershell?

Tags: windows, api, powershell, confluence

I'm trying to do the following script:

```
$EP = ExecutionPolicy

$Username = 'backup'

$Password = Get-Content 'C:\SecureString.txt' | ConvertTo-SecureString

$Cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Username, $Password

Import-Module VMware.DeployAutomation, ConfluencePS

if ($EP -eq 'Unrestricted') {
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
}

Set-ConfluenceInfo -BaseURI 'https://confluence.my.company' -PromptCredentials -Credential $Cred

Get-ConfluencePage
```

---

The problem is that even passing the variable with user and password it's still prompting me the authentication window and i didn't find any way to disable or avoid it.

Am I doing in the correct way?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using `-PromptCredentials` in `Set-ConfluenceInfo` so I think it's expected that it will ask for credentials.

Comment: THank you @robdy of course I'm using this command because I don't know any other. You are welcome to purpose an alternative that allows to pass credentials silently.

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://atlassianps.org/docs/ConfluencePS/commands/Set-Info/#-example-4-). Example 4 from linked doc is exactly what you need.

Comment: I already saw that, the problem is that i can't find the proper way to format user and password, I tried two variables one after the other, sepparated with comma... but nothing works.

Comment: Ah ok, please refer to [this link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/robcost/2008/05/01/powershell-tip-storing-and-using-password-credentials/) then. Your code looks OK, assuming that `SecureString.txt` contains properly saved password it should work (assuming also you supply correct username and corresponding password).

Comment: Problem solved, the solution was just removin -GetCredential and let ONLY -Credential.

Thank you anyway :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i was using both -PromptCredentials and -Credential the windows was prompted regardless it already had user and password, so the solution was about to remove -PromtCredentials command.

```
Set-ConfluenceInfo -BaseURI 'https://confluence.my.company' -Credential $Cred
```